# Boa Constructor Corrupting Code

Tags: python-2.7, ide, wxpython

I am using the Boa Constructor IDE (0.6.1-12) for development work in Python 2.7 and wxPython 2.8 under Linux Mint 17.3. However yesterday, for the second time in three months, it corrupted a .py file by inserting the same random string in a number of places. Clearing this absorbs time in both correcting the code and testing. I cannot understand why this randomly happens and also how to prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out that it was related to the 'paste' function of the paste facility on the scroll wheel  of the mouse causing inadvertent pastes when you copied and scrolled. Only happened occasionally - probably when under pressure or tired. The link is:-

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Input#Example%3a_Disabling_middle-mouse_button_paste_on_a_scrollwheel_mouse